# Java thread won't join

Tags: java

Okay I'm sure I'm missing something simple here but can't see it. I'm using a flag to end a thread and then joining it to clean up neatly, but the join never finishes it just gets stuck waiting. There is currently nothing in the thread's run loop so it isn't getting stuck in a separate loop.

Thread:

```
package com.nox.willywars;

public class GameThread extends Thread {

//{{Variables
private boolean running;
//}}

//{{Getters/Setters
public void setRunning(boolean running) {
    this.running = running;
}
//}}

//{{Constructor
public GameThread() {
    running = false;
}
//}}Constructor

//{{Public methods
@Override
public void run() {
    while(running) {
        ///...CODE GO HERE
    }
}

public boolean isRunning() {
    return running;
}
//}}
}
```

Code that fails to stop it:

```
//{{Lifecycle methods
@Override
public void create() {
    //LOAD! Probably debug temp
    TileFactory.load();

    mapScreen = new MapScreen();
    setScreen(mapScreen);

    gameThread = new GameThread();
    gameThread.setRunning(true);
    gameThread.start();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    killGameThread();
}

private void killGameThread() {
    if(gameThread != null) {
        if(gameThread.isAlive() && gameThread.isRunning()) {
            gameThread.setRunning(false);
            boolean retry = true;
            while(retry) {
                try {
                    gameThread.interrupt();
                    gameThread.join();
                    retry = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }
    gameThread = null;
    }
}
//}}
```

Currently it reaches gameThread.join() and gets stuck there, waiting for the thread to finish. Am I missing something here? As I understand the thread should finish once running is set to false and then joining should happen normally because it's already stopped.

**Edit:** Added some more code from the class that runs GameThread. Pause() is where KillGameThread is executed. I've made running volatile but it's had no effect.
I found another weird symptom too: Some people suggested looking at what's inside GameThread when it's stuck, so I went into the debugger. While join() is stuck I suspended the GameThread thread and saw it was on while(running), and running was definitely false. Then when I stepped over the code it exited the loop and finished correctly, seemingly caused by my debugging. It's as if the thread is somehow suspended?

Comment: Show us the class where you have `killGameThread()` and the `run()` method's code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first set the running flag as volatile

```
private volatile boolean running;
```

What does game thread do exactly, maybe it has blocked by some I/O operation.
and if the game thread doesn't sleep/wait/join, so interrupting it is useless.
you need to share the game thread code.

Comment: I didn't comment anything out, this is just basic architecture code and placeholding.

Comment: so you mean you don't anything inside the game thread run?! so making the running as volatile may help.

Comment: As Stephen C pointed out in his (excellent) answer, simply changing it to `volatile` may not necessarily be appropriate; the use of `interrupt()` requires appropriate handling, and the nature of the code that is going to be placed in the run loop also will have a big impact on how the thread should be stopped.

Comment: Thanks again guys, using volatile turned out to be the issue. running was indeed false but the while loop had cached the previous value!

Comment: for understanding volatile, you may need to check [this link](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#vol0) buddy. @nox

Answer (score 1):

As [user2511414 pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19631342/1344008), try with using [`volatile`](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml). In short, this will make sure the value od `running` is always accessed directly and not cached.

It setting `volatile` won't solve the situation, he problem most probably lays in the code section of a `GameThread#run` method that you commented out.

You can try using [`jstack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html) or [`jvisualvm`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) to get a *Thread Dump* of the thread you're trying to join.
This will at least show you where is it hanging, and may lead you to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `running` flag is not properly synchronised.  This could (in theory) result in the thread not noticing the state change ... due to the way that the Java memory model works.  You should either declare it as `volatile` or always access and update it in synchronized method calls (or synchronized blocks).

But (IMO) the real problem is in the way (actually the *ways*) that you are telling the thread to stop, and haw the thread is checking or responding.

- If you are going to use a flag to tell the thread to stop, then the thread needs to check that flag *frequently*.  If the thread could spend an indefinitely long amount of time doing *something else* between the checks, then it may never notice that it needs to stop.
- If you are going to use `Thread.interrupt()` then:

  - Your code should be calling `Thread.isInterrupted()` to test the thread's "interrupted" status instead of an ad-hoc flag.  Furthermore, it should be testing the status *regularly*.
  - Your code need to make sure that it handles the `InterruptedException` and `InterruptedIOException` properly.  This applies all the way up the call stack.

Note that calling `Thread.interrupt()` doesn't *actually* interrupt the thread in most cases.  In most cases, it just sets a flag that needs to be tested *manually*.  The only cases you get more than that is in certain blocking calls; e.g. `Object.wait(...)` and some IO calls.

---

You've left out most of the code where these things ought to happen.  The best we can say is that the problem is most likely in code you haven't shown us.

Comment: +1 for commenting on where the currently-unwritten code is heading.

Comment: Very good point regarding checking the flag at regular intervals, that hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: Looks like I've got it, just want to say thanks for your help and informative reply